# Can't commit to coredata

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to update my coredata entity but I can't work out how to commit the change.

I'm passing the a NSManagedobjectcontext object from a tableview tap and using this to display the info on the next screen.

My issue is whatever changes I make won't commit. I can't workout how to relate the passed object back to the core data. If I can't do it this way How do I select the right entity entry? Is there away to locate the key coredata uses?

Thanks

Here's the code

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
self.fetchedResultsController = [self fetchedResultsController];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sites == %@", results];

[request setPredicate:predicate];
Contact *writeobject = [context executeFetchRequest:request error: nil];
```

I'm now getting an error [contact name] unregcognized selector sent to instances

Comment: show some code - what's not working? Are you doing [moc save:&error]; ?

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
```

Is wrong because you should be setting the entity of the fetch request and what you're actually doing is creating a new managed object instance, inserting it into the context and setting it as the entity - which it isn't. So you get an exception the first time it's used.

Change your code to remove that line and create the fetch request using the entity name:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Contact"];
```

Comment: It isn't clear from your question what you're actually trying to achieve, but this should resolve your exception...

Comment: The exception is solved but the problem isn't 
Whenever the data that this method retries is edited the edits do not save to core data. They are lost between the transition of the screens. I am able to insert them ok its just updating them that is giving me the issue

Comment: `executeFetchRequest:error:` returns an array, not a `Contact` object. And you should always be checking for an error result. Most likely your fetch is returning nothing or that should also crash...